# Breadcrumb on custom category listing page Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, breadcrumbs

I am working on a theme which is customized by someone else.

So in

> `/websitename.com/app/design/frontend/rwd/ysv/template/page/category.phtml`

is created which is called.When I click on any category or subcategory.

I want to show breadcrumbs, when user is on category/sub-category page.

> echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->toHtml();
>   This will not help in my case i think.

```
System > Configuration > General > Web > Default Pages > Show Breadcrumbs for CMS Pages. is set to YES.
```

**Update:**

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
    .........
     <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>         <!-- Addedd -->
```

and

```
    <catalog_category_layered translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
      .....................
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                    <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.name.after" as="name.after" />
                    <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.after" as="after" />
                    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>     <!-- Addedd -->
```

In `page.xml`

```
<!-- category (default) -->
    <catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="root">
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/category.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
```

In `category.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head'); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start'); ?>

<!-- global messages -->
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices'); ?>

<!-- header -->
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header'); ?>

<!-- content -->
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content'); ?>

<!-- footer -->
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer'); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end'); ?>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter(); ?>
```

Can I create dynamic breadcrumbs based on current URL in a custom module or any other method? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can add breadcrumbs to your custom page using xml.
Add following xml code in your theme's **local.xml** file.

```
<module_controller_action translate="label">
   <reference name="breadcrumbs"> 
      <action method="addCrumb"> <!--add breadcrumb-->
         <name>home</name>
           <params> 
             <label>Home</label> 
             <title>Home</title> 
             <link>/</link> 
           </params> 
      </action>
      <action method="addCrumb"> <!--add breadcrumb-->
         <name>custompage</name>
           <params> 
             <label>custompage</label> 
             <title>custompage</title> 
             <link>/custom/page/link</link> 
           </params> 
      </action> 
   </reference>
</module_controller_action>
```

Comment: how i will decide that on which category i am ,

Comment: You asked for adding breadcrumbs in your custom module that's why I posted this answer. If you are looking for category, then follow @Piyush's answer

Answer (score 0):

For categories Just add below code in your `catalog.xml` for `catalog_category_layered` and `catalog_category_default` layout handle

```
<block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
```

For custom pages you can follow @Dinesh's Answer

**Update:** Along with Dinesh's answer if you want to set name and url dynamically you can use helper method for this. for eg:-

```
<action method="addCrumb">
    <!-- First breadcrumbs name -->
    <name helper="yourmodule/getName"/>
    <!-- add label, title, link  -->
    <params helper="yourmodule/getHomeUrl" />
</action>
```

In your helper function

```
public function getHomeUrl()
{
    return array(
        "label" => $this->__('Home'),
        "title" => $this->__('Home'),
        "link" => custom_url
    );
}


public function getName()
{
    return $name;
}
```

Add below code in `category.phtml` after `global_notices`

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?></div>
```

Comment: i updated my quetion

Comment: add the given code just after `<reference name="content">`

Comment: i am not on `frontend/rwd/default/template/page/2columns-right.phtml`

Comment: i am on `frontend/rwd/default/template/page/categories.phtml`

Comment: is it your custom page?

Comment: yes sir , this page is created

Comment: whenever i click on category this page is called

Comment: and what is your action for that page?

Comment: try adding this code in your custom layout file

Comment: @SaurabhRanjan check my updated answer

Comment: Means the only way is to create a module , get current page url and create breadcrumbs right ?

Comment: as per your updated question you are not using any default layout (1-column or 3 column) instead you are using `category.phtml` can you add code of your category.phtml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68690/discussion-between-saurabh-ranjan-and-piyush).